# My exe compiled using mono vbnc does not have the file version embedded

Tags: vb.net, mono

I am compiling a single .vb file in linux using mono vbnc.
I put the assembly information in the .vb file, but the compiled executable has the AssemblyVersion property as "AssemblyVersion".  The ProductVersion property contains the version info I specified.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("Test")>
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("My Test Executable")>
<Assembly: AssemblyCompany("Me Inc.")>
<Assembly: AssemblyProduct("Test")>
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright 2013")>
<Assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")>
<Assembly: ComVisible(False)>
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.0.0")>
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.0.0")>
<Assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.2.0.0")>
```

If I try to view the file properties, this is how they read:

```
File description       FileDescription
Type                   Application
File version           0.0.0.0
Product name           Test
Product version        1.2.0.0
Copyright              Copyright 2013
Original filename      OriginalFilename
```

Comment: please report a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/